# Can an Aryan be a disciple of a Mleccha?

Tags: scripture, vedas, guru, brahmins, mleccha

Can an Aryan/Arya (Brahmana) become a disciple of a Mleccha (Muslim)? Is it valid according to the Vedic scriptures?
I read in Mahabharata that it is forbidden to even hear the language of Mlecchas...
Kindly quote scriptural sources in an answer.

Comment: To me not clear if you mean the four vedas, or adjuncts like Brahmanas.